# SQL to get phpMyAdmin to show all duplicates and allow editing

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this

```
name        age
---------------
bob          22
dave         27
richard      25
stuart       27
```

I'd like to edit all the duplicates, rather than group them together.

So I'd like it to show me:

```
name        age
---------------
dave         27
stuart       27
```

And allow me to delete or edit them how I like.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
name, age
FROM
table
GROUP BY
age
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

But it simply groups them together and doesn't allow editing.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Added, sorry for the delay there.

Comment: You are looking at it backward I think .. Maybe start with writing an update statement, and then use a `select distinct` as the `where` clause?  Thoughts?  Either way you can't leave it to phpMyAdmin ...  You should be writing an entire SQL statment to do everything you need.  This way you know **why** everything is happening ..